# Searching for "all references" (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm working with VisualStudio 2013. On a WPF, c# Desktop application.

If I right click on something - say "WindowTitle" and choose "find all references" VS Shows me a list of all references in C# files (only .cs). If I use the menu edit-find in files (all files), VS Shows me a list C# and XAML (and config etc.) files.

For my uses, I want to see both the c#, and .xaml when searching for something.

Is it only possible with "find in files"?

Am I missing a concept - the way I learned it, is that XAML is used to generate code, so why isn't the XAML considered a "reference".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in my XAML I have a named control

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DGrid"/>
```

Then in my code-behind I click *'Find All References'* on a reference to DGrid, Visual Studio shows me the XAML references.

If in my XAML I have

```
`Value="{Binding Items}"`
```

Then in my ViewModel I click *'Find All References'* on my Items property, Visual Studio will not show me the XAML references, because it does not know which DataContext the property will apply to, the type is applied at runtime. There is no way for it to know.

Answer (score 1):

I myself use 'find usages' (shift + F12) for this rather than references, because indeed this is evaluated at run-time.

EDIT: as Phil noted, this is a feature of the Resharper extensions for vs. I will leave this answer here for users that use Resharper.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages__Finding_Usages_of_a_Symbol.html

Comment: I believe that this is a feature of Resharper and not of Visual Studio.

Comment: @PhilJollans you're completely right! it looked builtin to vs. I added it to the answer.